# Pandas Replace certain values in each column

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I have a dataframe which looks as below

```
+---+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------------------------+-----+----------+
|   | Pregnancies | Glucose | BloodPressure | SkinThickness | Insulin | BMI  | DiabetesPedigreeFunction | Age | Outcome  |
+---+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------------------------+-----+----------+
| 0 |           6 |   148.0 |          72.0 |          35.0 |   125.0 | 33.6 |                    0.627 |  50 |        1 |
| 1 |           1 |    85.0 |          66.0 |          29.0 |   125.0 | 26.6 |                    0.351 |  31 |        0 |
| 2 |           8 |   183.0 |          64.0 |          29.0 |   125.0 | 23.3 |                    0.672 |  32 |        1 |
| 3 |           1 |    89.0 |          66.0 |          23.0 |    94.0 | 28.1 |                    0.167 |  21 |        0 |
| 4 |           0 |   137.0 |          40.0 |          35.0 |   168.0 | 43.1 |                    2.288 |  33 |        1 |
+---+-------------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------------------------+-----+----------+
```

After watching the box plot for each variable.I found that they have outliers in them.

So in each column except `Outcome` I want to replace the values which are `greater than 95 percentile with value at 75 percentile` and values which are `less than 5 percentile with 25 percentile` of that particular column

For example in column `Glucose` values which are above 95 percentile I want to replace them with value at 75 percentile of `Glucose` column

How can I do this with pandas filter and percentile function

Any help for this will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` on all columns except `outcome`, with the functions `np.clip` and `np.percentile`:

```
import numpy as np

percentile_df = df.set_index('Outcome').apply(lambda x: np.clip(x, *np.percentile(x, [25,75]))).reset_index()

>>> percentile_df
   Outcome  Pregnancies  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin   BMI  \
0        1          6.0    148.0           66.0           35.0    125.0  33.6   
1        0          1.0     89.0           66.0           29.0    125.0  26.6   
2        1          6.0    148.0           64.0           29.0    125.0  26.6   
3        0          1.0     89.0           66.0           29.0    125.0  28.1   
4        1          1.0    137.0           64.0           35.0    125.0  33.6   

   DiabetesPedigreeFunction   Age  
0                     0.627  33.0  
1                     0.351  31.0  
2                     0.672  32.0  
3                     0.351  31.0  
4                     0.672  33.0
```

**[EDIT]** I misread the question at first, here is a way to change the 5th and 95th percentile to 25th and 75th respectively, using `np.select`:

```
def cut(column):
    conds = [column > np.percentile(column, 95),
             column < np.percentile(column, 5)]
    choices = [np.percentile(column, 75),
               np.percentile(column, 25)]
    return np.select(conds,choices,column)

df.set_index('Outcome',inplace=True)

df = df.apply(lambda x: cut(x)).reset_index()

>>> df
   Outcome  Pregnancies  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin   BMI  \
0        1          6.0    148.0           66.0           35.0    125.0  33.6   
1        0          1.0     89.0           66.0           29.0    125.0  26.6   
2        1          6.0    148.0           64.0           29.0    125.0  26.6   
3        0          1.0     89.0           66.0           29.0    125.0  28.1   
4        1          1.0    137.0           64.0           35.0    125.0  33.6   

   DiabetesPedigreeFunction   Age  
0                     0.627  33.0  
1                     0.351  31.0  
2                     0.672  32.0  
3                     0.351  31.0  
4                     0.672  33.0
```

Comment: I've never thought about it... why not? the documentation for `pd.np.clip` should just be the docs for `np.clip`. In any case, then I'll just delete the `pd.`

Comment: Never tried it myself, that's all. Also you can do `np.percentile(x, [25, 75])`. That version would get my vote :).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that's better!

Comment: What does `*np.percentile ` does.I read about `np.percentile` but  why `*`  is used

Comment: `np.percentile(x, [25, 75])` returns values for the 25th *and* the 75th percentile, so you need to unpack that using `*` so that the 25th percentile gets passed to `a_min` and the 75th percentile gets passed to `a_max` of `np.clip`

Comment: But I guess this replaces maximum value with 75th percentile.I want to replace values above 95 percentile with 75th percentile