# How to replace the highest 10 values in a column of a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv

Edit: Updated code with @Maow suggested changes.

I am currently doing a project which requires me to analyse data of wines. I have spotted some extreme outliers in each column of the csv file. In short, I have determined that the highest 10 values of each column must be replaced by the median value of that column. I have tried the following with help from 1 article ([Pandas Replace certain values in each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286615/pandas-replace-certain-values-in-each-column)), and I modified it as shown below, but unfortunately this is my first time with python and I have no idea what causing the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/hello/Downloads/winequality-red-ori.csv')

 def cut(column):
     condition = column > np.percentile(column,99.26470588) //Top 10 rows out of 1360 rows          
     replacewith = np.median(column) //replace with median
     np.select(condition.values.reshape(-1, 1), column.values, replacewith) //input changes

df.set_index(["citric acid", "quality"], inplace=True) //exclude citric acid and quality
df = df.apply(lambda x: cut(x)).reset_index()
df.to_csv('C:/Users/hello/Downloads/new.csv')
```

I have tried researching what causes the error including missing values in the csv file but I have none. I am also not sure if the above code will help me acheive my goal even without this error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: To you it is really useful to add a sample of you DataFrame. I went ahead and got it from kaggle, but when I run a Code snippet on Stackoverflow and get "File not found", I usually just ignore the question. Also comments in python start with `#`, not `//`, so this code cannot run.

Comment: @maow No problem I will include a dataset sample into the question,yes it's from kaggle . Regarding the //,thats the funny thing,Microsoft Visual Studio Code only lets me use #, I thought it would be // too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears because you use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) wrong. It expects, an array of condtions, an array of choices and a default value in this order.

It works with

```
np.select(condition.values.reshape(-1, 1), column.values, replacewith)
```

1. You are using a numpy function on pandas objects. This may work, but accessing the underlying `np.array` is imho good practice.
2. Also `np.select` is not doing what you think it does. Its purpose is to select a single element from an array according to the first hit in a list of conditions. So you basically select the first value that belongs to the 10 largest.

Final Note: By calling `set_index` twice, you are basically making `citric acid` a value again. You should call

```
df.set_index(["citric acid", "quality"], inplace=True)  # exclude citric acid and quality
```

EDIT:
The `np.select` function expects a `list of bool ndarrays` i.e. a 2d datastructure as per documentation. If you look at `condition` this looks like this.

```
In [35]: condition
Out[35]: array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False])
```

`.reshape` will change the shape of the array. `-1` is a shortcut to leave the number of rows the same and `1` means that you create a redundant ndarrray with only one element in each row.

```
In [36]: condition.reshape(-1, 1)
Out[36]: 
array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       ...,
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]])
```

This is to match the expected signature.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, all the columns which I would like to exclude should be included in only 1 set_index function call. Regarding the np.select, could you explain what reshape(-1,1) does?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an algorithm:

```
condition = column > np.percentile(column,99.26470588)         
    replacewith = np.median(column) #replace with median
    return np.where(condition,replacewith,column.values)
```